# Using batch file to import sql file

Tags: mysql, batch-file

This is the contents of my batch file.

```
@echo on
C:\xampp\xampp_start
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -e "DROP DATABASE db_pepper";
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db_pepper";
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root db_pepper ^< C:\Pepper\sqldumps\db_pepper.sql
C:\xampp\xampp_stop
pause
```

i am having a problem in the part where i import the db_pepper.sql to db_pepper. It won't work. If i remove the ^, it will be treated as less than.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -p db_pepper < C:\Pepper\sqldumps\db_pepper.sql

Comment: i can't believe it. i should've ignored when the command line shows 0< instead of <. i removed the -p so it wouldn't wait for the password. but it solved my problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a batch file 
Step 2 : Put this command line:
@echo on
c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.20\bin\msyql - root -D YOURDatabase --force < file.sql

Example: c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.20\bin\msyql - root -D ddroid509ht --force < C:\users\Pc\Desktop\file.sql

This working for me